# WPF filtering dataset DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filtering

I have amended this slightly.  My request is for help creating a filter based on two checkboxes (checkBoxSD & CheckBoxTech)  If both are ticked I want to see all rows where the SD assigned to is either Tech or Service desk.  If one is ticked I only want to see row with that name in.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Database3DataSet x:Key="database3DataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="live_DataViewSource" Source="{Binding Live_Data, Source={StaticResource database3DataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource live_DataViewSource}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="live_DataDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,76,120,46.5" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iDColumn" Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sD_Assign_toColumn" Binding="{Binding SD Assign to}" Header="SD Assign to" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxTech" Content="Tech" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.08,-2.533"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBoxSD" Content="Service Desk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

I have been asked for the Collection view source, is this it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        WpfApp1.Database3DataSet database3DataSet = ((WpfApp1.Database3DataSet)(this.FindResource("database3DataSet")));
        // Load data into the table Live_Data. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApp1.Database3DataSetTableAdapters.Live_DataTableAdapter database3DataSetLive_DataTableAdapter = new WpfApp1.Database3DataSetTableAdapters.Live_DataTableAdapter();
        database3DataSetLive_DataTableAdapter.Fill(database3DataSet.Live_Data);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource live_DataViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("live_DataViewSource")));
        live_DataViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    private void live_DataDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Maybe I am too much of a noob for this task.

Thanks

Phil

Comment: Post your code where you set your CollectionViewSource.Source to your database set.

Comment: Do you mean this?

Comment: Edit your Table Adapter and add SQL query with Parameters to filter your results based on it [Create and configure TableAdapters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6sb6kb28(v=vs.140).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: I can manual change the SQL query and that works fine but I am trying to get this to change using checkbox.   I have 5 teams in the assign column and I want to be able to tick the relevant box to display their task.  I need them to have the option of selecting multiple boxes and see one combine list.

Comment: I am using the Data source option in Visual Studio for create the connection, is this making it more complicated?

Comment: From what I am reading\watching I need to convert the access database (DataSet) into a collection and then Filter the collection.

Comment: The way to do that is using entity framework. [Here is a very easy example to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-with-wpf-and-entity-framework-6). And it will show you how to filter your objects.

Comment: Thank you for point me in the right direction.  I seen that post but was thinking it would only work with SQL servers.

Comment: Entity framework only wants to connect to an SQL database.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can use [JetEntityFrameworkProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetEntityFrameworkProvider/6.1.4). It is Entity framework 6.x provider for Microsoft Access (Jet) files. Or you can search for an EntityFramework for your specific database engine.